# Laravel 5 group by

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have 2 tables `Items` and `Sets`. How can I make a query to group them by parent_item

**Items**

- id
- name

**Sets**

- id
- item (belongs to `Items`)
- parent_item (belongs to `Items`)

Data looks like

**Items**

1, Item #1
2, Item #2
3, Item #3
4, Item #4

**Sets**

Id: 1, Item: 1, Parent Item: 3
Id: 2, Item: 2, Parent Item: 3
Id: 3, Item: 2, Parent Item: 4
Id: 4, Item: 3, Parent Item: null
Id: 5, Item: 4, Parent Item: null

I want to group data in a way

```
{
    3: [1,2],
    4: [2],
    'other': [3,4]
}
```

Comment: would you like to show your relations between items and sets?

Comment: @ChiragPatel will update now

Comment: if you want to apply group by only sets table then you can do this $data = model_name:: select('item','Parent Item')->groupBy('Parent Item');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a `Set` model and the column name for **Parent Item** is `parent_item` you can do the following

```
Set::get()->groupBy('parent_item');
```

If you don't have a model and the column name for **Parent Item** is `parent_item`

```
DB::table('Sets')->get()->groupBy('parent_item')
```